# getting json file behind login page with curl

Tags: php, json, curl

I'm trying to get json data from this page https://www.rbauction.com/rba-api/search/results/advanced?rbasq=YXJ8Tj00Mjk0MjM4MzMyKzQyOTQ5NjU3OTg=&offset=2&count=1&ccb=USD

when i visit that page from browser it will ask me to login, when logged in it will display the json right away upon login. what need to do is get that json data with php using curl.

```
$username = 'myemail';
    $password = 'mypass';
    $loginurl = 'https://www.rbauction.com/myaccount';

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginurl);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '_58_login='.$username.'&_58_password='.$password);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

   // $store = curl_exec($ch);

    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.rbauction.com/rba-api/search/results/advanced?rbasq=YXJ8Tj00Mjk0MjM4MzMyKzQyOTQ5NjU3OTg%3D&offset=2&count=1&ccb=USD');

    $store = curl_exec($ch);

    var_dump($store);
```

when i do var_dump its just showing empty string

Comment: did you check the browser's network tab to see what happens after login. Maybe the site redirects, and your curl code isn't following those.

Comment: i think it does redirects but im not sure how to handle that will curl

Comment: curlopt_followredirect. look it up.

Comment: ok i added curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);  but i get http 302 error

Comment: and then after refreshing back to empty string

Comment: yes, because you TURNED OFF follow by setting it to false. so you got a 302 (redirect) header, and since you told curl to not follow it, that's where everything stops.

Comment: yeah i just noticed that, i set it to true, but now it just shows login page

Comment: ´first login with curl `$store = curl_exec($ch);`, save the cookies and don't close curl, next, get the json, again, data `$store = curl_exec($ch);`. Make sure you use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);`

Comment: it just shows login page